# First $3$ non-zero terms of the Maclaurin Series $\frac{1}{\sqrt{4+x^3}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

Since each derivative will be multiplied by $3x^2$, are all the terms of this Maclaurin series $0$?

Comment: If every term if being multiplied by 3x^2, when we calculate f at 0, the coefficient will be 0.

Comment: We have $f(0)\ne 0$. Certainly $f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0)=0$. You will find $f'''(0)\ne 0$. But there are more efficient ways to find the Maclaurin series in this case.

Comment: I see. Did u compute the derivative to see this? If not, how did you see it?

Comment: I dd it without writing in two ways: (i) The thing looks like $(1+t)^{-1/2}$, with different constants and $t$ replaced by $x^3$, so the first non-zero coefficients will be at$n=0,3,6$: (ii) When we differentiate once we get a $3x^2g(x)$, twice we get a $6xg(x)$ with other stuff added, three times we get $6g(x)$  with other stuff added.

Answer (score 1):

To find the Maclaurin series, first find the series for
$$f(x) = {1\over \sqrt{4 + x}}$$
then do the substitution $x \leftarrow x^3$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the generalized binomial theorem

> $$ (4+x^3)^{-1/2}= \frac{1}{2}(1+x^3/4)^{-1/2} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {-1/2 \choose k } \frac{x^{3k}}{4^k}, $$

where

> $$ {-1/2 \choose k } =\frac{(-1/2)!}{k!(-1/2-k)!}. $$

Answer (score 1):

Your answer lies within the question, it states to find the first three **non-zero terms**. It is a trick question as the first two derivatives are indeed zero at $f'(0)$ and $f''(0)$ but keep differentiating and don't forget to use the product rule and you shall be rewarded with an answer for your efforts.

Oh I am still new here and unfortunately don't have enough rep to comment yet, so I apologise as this next statement should be a comment:

@Mhenni do you think $(-1/2)!$ should be written as $\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)=\sqrt\pi$ to avoid the confusion of negative factorials maybe with a link to the [Gamma Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) that generalises the factorial notation?